# Access denied error when trying to access Lanmanserver

Tags: .net, vbscript, windows-server-2008

Im trying to access the Lanmanserver via the ADSI WinNT using a vb script,

```
Set FileShare = GetObject("WinNT://wn0home/LanmanServer")

For Each ShareObj in FileShare
    WScript.Echo ShareObj.Name & " = " & ShareObj.Path
Next
```

However, I keep getting *Active Directory: General access denied error*

Anyone here familiar with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line should be,

```
WScript.Echo ShareObj.Name & " = " & ShareObj.AdsPath
```